# Xamarin Insights Still Requires Subscription

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, hockeyapp

Shortly after Microsoft's announcement that Xamarin would be free with Visual Studio, they announced Insights merge with HockeyApp.

When I follow the Insights guide here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/insights/getting-started/

I only get to the new app setup before I receive the error:

> An active Xamarin Platform license is required to add applications to Insights.

I've been trying to find out where to put my visual studio enterprise license code in the Xamarin portal so I can get some crash analytics with my mobile app.

I see notifications everywhere mentioning the merge with HockeyApp but I haven't found anything that says Insights is being deprecated. A 'merge' to me by definition implies that both HockeyApp and Insights are changing and they both should now be the same service.

Does anyone know the process for crash analytics in Xamarin? It looks like it's been months since their announcement but I haven't found clear direction for new mobile applications.

Comment: Insights is only available to accounts who are grandfathered in.  Moving forward, they are encouraging Insights and HA users to migrate to the new VS Mobile Center (mobile.azure.com) although there is still not feature parity with the older two platforms.  However, if you are primarily interested in Crash analytics that is available in Mobile Center.

Comment: @Jason it seems like an answer but is posted as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insights is only available to accounts who are grandfathered in. Moving forward, they are encouraging Insights and HA users to migrate to the new VS Mobile Center (mobile.azure.com) although there is still not feature parity with the older two platforms. However, if you are primarily interested in Crash analytics that is available in Mobile Center.